# Concatenate CSV files using OS command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to combine a directory of CSV files within a Python script. I have tried using Pandas to achieve this but it seems inefficient as a OS command could achieve the same thing without a library like this...

```
copy *.csv merged_files.csv
```

Is there a way to run an OS command like this inside of a Python3 script?

Comment: Look at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). E.g., `subprocess.run(['copy', '*.txt', 'merged.txt'], shell=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to retrive the output of the command to put it in a variable you can simply use:

```
import os
os.system('your command here')
```

This will make your script execute a shell command when run.

**EDIT:** I stumbled upon a much more [well written and advanced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/11739938) from someone for sure more experienced than me on the topic, please refer to it for a more in-depth view on your question!